# Plural of "A good night's sleep"

Tags: grammatical-number, expressions

Is it possible to have a plural of "A good night's sleep"?

Would "Some good nights' sleep" be correct?

**Edit:**

I'm thinking specifically in the sentence: "I'm looking forward to a good night's sleep"

Comment: I think most contexts where you'd refer to "A good night's sleep" don't really admit of a plural in the first place, since the night in question is usually being contrasted (implicitly or explicitly) with preceding or following sleep-deprived nights. I personally would probably try to avoid the plural by restructuring my utterance. But I'm the kind of wuss who avoids pluralising *tablespoonful*, for example, simply because both alternatives seem a bit odd to me.

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

> Some good nights' sleep

is grammatically correct.

Answer (score 1):

It would lose its idiomatic nature. The trope "a good [noun]" is used in many other expressions, and this particular version depends on that, not on the object "night's sleep".

Consider these parallel constructions:

> I must have had a good two gallons of beer that night.
>
> It was a good three weeks before we ever saw a dime of the money.
>
> We were a good mile and a half from home when the care gave out.

Comment: Wow, so the "good" in "a good night's sleep" refers to the quantity rather than the quality of the sleep? I'd never thought of that.

Comment: In the sense that the quantity of sleep is actually a quality in this case. What "a good [something]" means is more like "ample" or "at least" — it expresses the idea that something is probably more than the stated amount, but we're rounding down.

Comment: I don't think it is an example of that construction. Partly because that construction generally requires and explicit number, and partly because it does not imply "more than a night's sleep", which is what the idiom you are referring to means. And as Pablo says, I find "several good nights' sleep" completely idiomatic

Comment: I'm sure the understanding of the phrase varies though. I think to many people, "a good night's sleep" and "a great night's sleep" would be interchangeable, with the latter being an exceptionally good night's sleep.

Comment: @Colin: If your comment was an answer I'd upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd avoid *some*, since it would usually be heard as "some (good night's sleep)," i.e. some quality sleeping time in one night.  To avoid tying myself in knots like that, I'd usually rephrase:

> "I slept well for several nights."

or even

> "I had a good night's sleep for several nights."